# Adding a hash to jsonb column in active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am returning a params hash in a controller.

```
params[:questions] = {"ad6d1d19-f95b-228c-8a19-49150ad15f23"=>"answer21", "90783719-9cd6-23de-f3fb-9bc80e7a72a0"=>"answer22"}
```

With multiple key value pairs.
I have model **Model1**. This has a json column called `answers`.
Every time a params[:questions] is returned. I'm trying a create a `Model1` object as follows:

```
Model1.create(answers: {q_id: the_id, ans: the_answer})
```

How can I create multiple key value pair `answers` column? If I iterate through the `params[:questions]` and create an object, it will create a new object for every pair. So that's not a solution.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show some code? Where does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
m = Model1.new
params[:questions].each do |id, answer|
  m.answers << {q_id: id, ans: answer}
end
m.save!
```

or maybe

```
hash = {} 
params[:questions].each do |id, answer|
  hash << {q_id: id, ans: answer}
end
Model1.create(answers: hash
```

)